# How to detect unreachable target hosts in ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, runtime-error, host

I wish to grab in a variable `sshreachable` if a target hosts `all_hosts` are reachable or not.

I wrote the below playbook for the same.

```
- name: Play 3- check telnet nodes
  hosts: localhost
  ignore_unreachable: yes


   - name: Check all port numbers are accessible from current host
     include_tasks: innertelnet.yml
     with_items: "{{ groups['all_hosts'] }}"
```

cat innertelnet.yml

```
---

       - name: Check ssh connectivity
         block:

           - raw: "ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@{{ item }} echo success"
             ignore_errors: yes
             register: sshcheck

           - debug:
               msg: "SSHCHECK variable:{{ sshcheck }}"

           - set_fact:
               sshreachable: 'SSH SUCCESS'
             when: sshcheck.unreachable == 'false'
           - set_fact:
               sshreachable: 'SSH FAILED'
             when: sshcheck.unreachable == 'true'

       - debug:
           msg: "INNERSSH1: {{ sshreachable }}"
```

Unfortunately, i get error like below:

Output:

```
TASK [raw] *********************************************************************
    fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.9.9.126 closed.", "skip_reason": "Host localhost is unreachable", "unreachable": true}
    
        TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
        task path:

    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "SSHCHECK variable:{'msg': u'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.9.9.126 closed.', 'unreachable': True, 'changed': False}"
    }

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'sshreachable' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/playbook/checkssh/innertelnet.yml': line 45, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n       - debug:\n         ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.0.116.194                : ok=101  changed=1    unreachable=9    failed=0    skipped=12   rescued=0    ignored=95  
localhost          : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=1    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can you please suggest changes to my code to get this to work?

Comment: your logic has faults. the `sshcheck` variable doesnt have a `unreachable` or `reachable` attributes to take decision upon it. add a debug task to inspect the variable when the `raw` command succeeds or fails, and you will confirm that. Then you will be able to decide which fields to use for determining if host is up or down, if you still want to continue with your current code.

Comment: i havent worked on a similar problem to give u a solid answer. i would probably look into using a `wait_for` task with `delegate_to` the localhost looping for all the servers you want, and the service you expect to be running (ssh/telnet). to fix your code's logic though, it seems to me you could take the decision that a server is down when the `sshreachable` is undefined.

Comment: I actually wonder if you want the [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html) module, which I use frequently to test if a host is accessible (e.g., waiting for a cloud instance to spin up) before attempting to run tasks against it.

Comment: I have added the debug and shared the ouput in my original post update Dear @ilias-sp

Comment: I need this for logging purpose. Whether the target server ssh connectivity from Ansible server successed or failed at a point of time when the automation is run. @larsk

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that `sshreachable` variable is not getting set as the `when:` condition does not match. I.e. `sshcheck.unreachable` might not be something returned by `raw`.

For this purpose, `command` module should be enough, and we can evaluate the return code of the command to `set_fact`.

You could do something like:

```yaml
- block:
  - command: ssh -o BatchMode=yes user@host1 echo success
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: sshcheck
  - set_fact:
      sshreachable: "{{ sshcheck is success }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Host1 reachable: {{ sshreachable | string }}"
```

Update:

`raw` module seems to work the same way. Example (including **@mdaniel**'s valuable input):

```yaml
- block:
  - raw: ssh -o BatchMode=yes user@host1 echo success
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: sshcheck
  - set_fact:
      sshreachable: SSH SUCCESS
    when: sshcheck is success
  - set_fact:
      sshreachable: SSH FAILED
    when: sshcheck is failed

- debug:
    msg: "Host1 reachable: {{ sshreachable }}"
```

Comment: [`when: sshcheck is failed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#task-results) (and its `is success` friend) is the preferred syntax for that, also abbreviated as `- set_fact: sshreachable: "{{ sshcheck is success }}"`

Comment: @mdaniel  Seshadri_C both your solution works !! but only with `command` module which has python dependency on target host. Any solution to make this work with `raw` module please i.e no python dependency??

Comment: @Ashar I believe `raw` works in the same way. I will update the answer. @mdaniel - thanks for the nice tip!

Comment: The solution that works with `raw` module is  FAILED -> `when: ssh is unreachable` SUCCESS ->  `when: not ssh is unreachable`

Comment: In this case @Seshadri_C `raw` module works differently than the `command` module!! Please test and share your experience.

Comment: Just tried it out, works with Ansible 2.9.x. See the "Update"